# Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-social-facebook

Getting *Proxy Authentication Required* error while retrieving Facebook user profile.

> RestTemplate: GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=id%2Cabout%2Cage_range%2Caddress%2Cbio%2Cbirthday%2Ccontext%2Ccover%2Ccurrency%2Cdevices%2Ceducation%2Cemail%2Cfavorite_athletes%2Cfavorite_teams%2Cfirst_name%2Cgender%2Chometown%2Cinspirational_people%2Cinstalled%2Cinstall_type%2Cis_verified%2Clanguages%2Clast_name%2Clink%2Clocale%2Clocation%2Cmeeting_for%2Cmiddle_name%2Cname%2Cname_format%2Cpolitical%2Cquotes%2Cpayment_pricepoints%2Crelationship_status%2Creligion%2Csecurity_settings%2Csignificant_other%2Csports%2Ctest_group%2Ctimezone%2Cthird_party_id%2Cupdated_time%2Cverified%2Cvideo_upload_limits%2Cviewer_can_send_gift%2Cwebsite%2Cwork" resulted in 407 (Proxy Authentication Required); invoking error handler

Comment: are you behing a proxy or firewall? ... and that blocks facebook?

Comment: Yes..I have passed proxy hostname and port. How to provide proxy username and password..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but what I have used before is:

`System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");`

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. Looks username and password are not picked from system properties.